# CMVT and multiple derivative problem

Tags: real-analysis

In a previous exercise, I used the CMVT to find that for a function $f$ differentiable on an open interval $I$ containing 0 and $f(0)=0$, then $\exists c\in(0,x)$ s.t. $f(x)=\frac{f'(c)}{c^{n-1}}\frac{x^n}{n}$.

Now I need to use that result and induction to show that if $f$ is $n$-times differentiable on $I$ and if $f^{(k)}(0)=0, k\in[0,n-1]\cap\mathbb{N}$, then $\exists c\in(0,x)$ s.t. $f(x)=f^{(n)}(c)\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

My only thought to try is to use the previous result that $f(x)=\frac{f'(c)}{c^{n-1}}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and take the derivative, but that comes out pretty messy and therefore probably doesn't put me on the right track. Do I use CMVT again? How do I incorporate the assumption that $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0, 1, \ldots, n-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, thinking inductively, there is, as you observed, a $c\in (0,x)$, such that
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x^n/n}=\frac{f'(c)}{c^{n-1}}.
$$ 
Next, using again CMVT, there is a $c_1\in (0,c)$, such that
$$
\frac{f'(c)}{c^{n-1}}=\frac{f''(c_1)}{(n-1)c_1^{n-2}}.
$$
Next, using once again CMVT, there is a $c_2\in (0,c_1)$, such that
$$
\frac{f''(c_1)}{(n-1)c^{n-2}_1}=\frac{f'''(c_2)}{(n-2)(n-1)c_2^{n-3}}.
$$
Etc.